# Getting the MySQL C API working with MinGW

Tags: c++, mysql, c

It's been days searching for a way to get the MySQL C API working with a MinGW compiler, and frankly I have to say this is getting very frustrating.

I'm trying to compile the minimal example:

```
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("MySQL client version: %s\n", mysql_get_client_info());

  exit(0);
}
```

and I keep on getting:

```
[Linker Error] undefined reference to `mysql_get_client_info@0'
```

I have compiled the libraries (including libmysql.a which contains mysql_get_client_info) and properly linked them, included all include and lib directories properly. Basiacly, everything is done by the letter according not only to the tutorials but also to forum posts which dealt specifically with this problem.

Now, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: show us _how_ you've linked the files together, and how you compiled the code... MySQL C was written to be C99 compliant, and MS didn't support C99 until recently I believe (could be that it still doesn't)

Comment: The compiler is gcc (not VC) and I did set the -std=c99 flag. Same problem. By the way, I am using the DevCpp IDE and I added the .a library in the compiler options as I usually do.

Comment: show the C flags, too... just show the full compilation command/make file

Comment: Right, here is the makefile (won't post it here for obvious reasons): http://textuploader.com/1o9n

Comment: I can't see everything here... like the `-lmysqlclient` flag... I only develop on linux systems, though, but I'd expect to see the `mysql_config --cflags --libs` params in the make file

Comment: By the gods, you are right! I forgot to link the libmysqlclient.a library! Right, now how do I flag your answer as accepted?

Comment: I've posted the comment as an answer. Any up-/acceptance votes would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Yeah I can't up yet (requires 15 votes) but accpeted. Thanks again dude!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having looked at your make-file, it would appear you've forgotten the mysql flags, required for your code to compile. On linux, you'd have to include the output of `mysql_config --cflags --libs` in the make file.
Add those to your makefile and the code should compile just fine.